# How I can solve: HTML template must contain a single root element

Tags: javascript, html, file, navigator

I'm trying to use onsen navigator with multiple ".html" files, but I get the same error, no matters what I've tried

My scenario

- -www
- /scripts
- index.html
- home.html

I want to go from index.html, to home.html

The error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Onsen UI] HTML template must contain a single root element
    at Object.Q.throw (onsenui.min.js:2)
    at Object.Q.createElement (onsenui.min.js:2)
    at onsenui.min.js:2
```

My index.html:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

    <script src='scripts/loginScript.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Tu Psicologa de Cabecera</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator id="navigator" page="index.html"></ons-navigator>
        <ons-template id="index.html">
            <ons-page id="index">
                <img class="imagenLogo" src="https://i.imgur.com/cq7BbWn.png">

                <ons-card class="loginCard">
                    <ons-input id="userLogin" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Usuario" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px;" float></ons-input>
                    <ons-input id="passLogin" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Contraseña" type="password" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px;" float></ons-input>

                    <ons-button class="loginButton" onclick="loginNomral()">ENTRAR</ons-button>
                    <ons-button class="loginFacebookButton">ENTRAR CON FACEBOOK</ons-button>
                    <label class="labelRegister">REGISTRARME</ilabel>
                </ons-card>
            </ons-page>
        </ons-template>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
```

My home.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-page id="home">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Page 1</ons-back-button></div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <p>This is the second page.</p>
    </ons-page>
</body>
</html>
```

And my script:

```
    function loginNomral(){
        const navigator = document.querySelector('#navigator');
        navigator.resetToPage('home.html');

        ons.notification.alert('test');
    }
```

Please help :v
**EDIT:**
This is for a mobile app
Full html view:
[Image index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjuYp.png)
[Image home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1QVS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple, after some hours, just I removed all the html format and I keep the  tag.

From this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-page id="home">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Page 1</ons-back-button></div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <p>This is the second page.</p>
    </ons-page>
</body>
</html>
```

to this:

```
<ons-page id="home">
    <ons-card class="loginCard">
        <ons-input id="userLogin" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Usuario" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px;" float></ons-input>
        <ons-input id="passLogin" modifier="underbar" placeholder="Contraseña" type="password" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px;" float></ons-input>

        <ons-button class="loginButton" onclick="logintest()">ENTRAR</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="loginFacebookButton">ENTRAR CON FACEBOOK</ons-button>
        <label class="labelRegister">REGISTRARME</ilabel>
    </ons-card>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: Actually, your problem was not with the structure of the document. It was with template id. 
    `navigator.resetToPage('home.html');` It seems, you were calling a non existing id. I have onsen app inside a regular html page and it works

Answer (score -1):

as it seems from your code you have `</head>` without a opening `<head>`

but the main problem is that you cant have 2 tags as the root, meaning you will need to wrap them with a single `<html></html>` tag

like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>My First Heading</h1>
      <p>My first paragraph.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "seems", not "sesames"?

Comment: @HereticMonkey In fairness, it's better as sesames.

Comment: I removed that but still isn't work, I added links to the images of the files

Comment: @DaveNewton That's why I asked and didn't just edit it ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'd bet that you are creating components of some sort... and those components look like this:

```
<header>...</header>

<section>...</section>
```

Which... has 2 'root' elements... right?

```
<aside class='component-name'>
  <header>...</header>

  <section>...</section>
</aside>
```

This has 1.

Comment: Ok, so, how I can apply that on my files?

Comment: I don't know anything about https://onsen.io/ - but you should ask them.

Answer (score -1):

Onsen UI navigator works with templates where you specify your page content, you do not need to create different html file to specify a different page

```js
document.addEventListener('init', function(event) {
  var page = event.target;

  if (page.id === 'page1') {
    page.querySelector('#push-button').onclick = function() {
      document.querySelector('#myNavigator').pushPage('page2.html', {data: {title: 'Page 2'}});
    };
  } else if (page.id === 'page2') {
    page.querySelector('ons-toolbar .center').innerHTML = page.data.title;
  }
});
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator swipeable id="myNavigator" page="page1.html"></ons-navigator>

<template id="page1.html">
  <ons-page id="page1">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page 1</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <p>This is the first page.</p>

    <ons-button id="push-button">Push page</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</template>

<template id="page2.html">
  <ons-page id="page2">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Page 1</ons-back-button></div>
      <div class="center"></div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <p>This is the second page.</p>
  </ons-page>
</template>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know, but the project will be very large and it is not convenient for me to have everything in an html file for later maintenance

Comment: Ok, if that's the case you will have to write your own pageLoader (I guess), you can still following the same pattern using templates (Just like angular 1) instead of creating the whole HTML structure, review the pageLoader property